# Gallery not displaying requested image using intent in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to load an image in gallery from my application but the gallery displays distorted shape but not actual image. Here is the image loaded.
[image: Distorted image]

Here is my code to load the image in gallery. I am using helper class to find uri about the image.

```
public class FileHelper
{
    public static FileHelper Instance { get; } = new FileHelper();

    public async Task<Android.Net.Uri> GetFileUri(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {
        var filePath = GetFullFilePath(fileName);
        if (!FileExists(filePath))
        {
            await SaveFileInDevice(file, filePath);
        }

        Android.Net.Uri uri;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://" + filePath);
        else
            uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + filePath);
        return uri;
    }

    private async Task SaveFileInDevice(byte[] file, string filePath)
    {
        using (var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath))
        {
            await fileOutputStream.WriteAsync(file);
        }
    }

    private string GetFullFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        var directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).Path, "Geo Mobiz");

        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileName);

        return filePath;
    }

    private bool FileExists(string filePath)
    {
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
        return file.Exists();
    }
}
```

Here is my code to display image in gallery.

```
string fileName = MessageText.Text.Trim();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
        String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        Android.Net.Uri uri = await FileHelper.Instance.GetFileUri(file, fileName);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        if (intent.ResolveActivity(context.PackageManager) != null)
            context.StartActivity(intent);
        else
            Helpers.CustomToastHelper.Show(context, "Unable to open file");
```

First, I am getting file name from my message box and it is coming from external web service. Also the byte array is retrieved from external data. I pass both of these values to the FileHelper class and it saves the image but when I try to see it in default gallery image it displays distorted image like above.

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `am trying to load an image in gallery`. No. What i see is that you create an image file in your devices storage. After that you use an intent to let the user choose an app that can display the image file.

Comment: You should first check if the amount of bytes you received are equal to file length. And equal to original file length.